# React component error: expected a string or a class/function but got undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

I am getting the following error in a create-react-app. `Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

The app is currently a super-basic - it just imports and renders one single component:

```
import './App.css';
import { PasswordInput } from 'gg-react-test-lib';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PasswordInput />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I am therefore assuming that the problem is with my component library that I am importing the PasswordInput component from. I am installing it from NPM.

It has an index.js file like:

````
import Radio from './Radio/Radio';

export { PasswordInput, Radio }```

Those component files themselves do a default export at the bottom of the file e.g.: 
`export default PasswordInput;`

I have a pretty minimal webpack.config.js file in my component library repo: 

```const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/index.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin()]
    },
};
````

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "gg-react-test-lib",
  "version": "1.0.7",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "module": "src/index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "clsx": "^1.0.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }
}
```

.babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```

Comment: gg-react-test-lib is this is the library ? i didnt find any library named this in npmjs.org can you add the url to the package so it will be helpful

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gg-react-test-lib

Comment: Did you configure babel with the appropriate preset ? eg: @babel/preset-react ?

Comment: Yep, I installed  @babel/preset-react. ```"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.7.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "webpack": "^4.41.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"
  }```